# Как сделать, чтоб при скролинге блок становился fixed и уходил в левый верхний угол?

Tags: javascript, css3

```
.neon {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  color: red;
}
div p { margin:0; }
#neon:hover { text-shadow: 0 0 200px red,0 0 80px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed; 
}
#neon {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
}
#neon span {
  animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
}

<div class="neon">
  <p id="neon">S<span>l</span>ider</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```js
(function(d) {

  "use strict";

  window.onscroll = function() {
    funcScroll();
  };


  function funcScroll() {
    var topbar = d.getElementsByClassName('neon')[0],
        scrollTop = d.body.scrollTop;

    if (scrollTop > 150) {
      topbar.classList.add('fixed');
    } else {
      topbar.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
  }

})(document);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 1500px;
}

.neon {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red, 0 0 30px FireBrick, 0 0 6px DarkRed;
  color: red;
  transition: .3s;
}

div p {
  margin: 0;
}

#neon:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 200px red, 0 0 80px FireBrick, 0 0 6px DarkRed;
}

#neon {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red, 0 0 30px FireBrick, 0 0 6px DarkRed;
}

#neon span {
  animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="neon">
  <p id="neon">S<span>l</span>ider</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Eсли используешь jQuery то можно и так:**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var topScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

   if(topScroll >= 100) {
      $('.neon').addClass('fixed');
   } else {
      $('.neon').removeClass('fixed');
   }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 1500px;
}
.fixed.neon {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 120px;
}
.neon {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
div p { margin:0; }
#neon:hover { text-shadow: 0 0 20px red,0 0 12px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed; 
}
#neon {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
}
#neon span {
  animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="neon">
  <p id="neon">S<span>l</span>ider</p>
</div>
```